# Make login page on root of website

Tags: c#, asp.net

Using asp.net how would you achieve having the login page on the root of the website so for example, the login page to be on www.helloworld.com rather than having a separate file for the login www.helloworld.com/login.aspx

Does any understand what I am trying to do?

Additional information:

Just to give you some examples, look at this website www.torn.com then look at this one www.mobslife.com.. Notice how the url for the login page is just www.torn.com but on www.mobslife.com it is www.mobslife.com/login.php

Comment: Please advise what you have tried so far. You can create logic in your controller to reroute to the login page if they are not logged in (based on session data).

Comment: @BrianGerhards you are talking about ASP.Net MVC (where requested behavior is trivial), but OP made no indication that they looking for MVC solution, especially with "login.aspx" (which strongly hints to WebForms).

Comment: @BrianGerhards Updated question

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Updated question

Comment: Your update does not clarify what type of solution you are looking for and what framework you use. It was already relatively clear what the goal is without adding links to some really random looking sites (and potentially making question target for "this is potential spam" flagging).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Look how the torn.com website doesn't redirect you to "login.php" but mobslife does.. how do i make my website do that? So the login page is on mywebsite.com rather than mywebsite.com/login.php

Comment: @mogorilla please advise what framework you are using. Are you using an MVC framework? Are you calling individual pages? I'm sure these professionally built pages are using some sort of MVC framework, but that is only an assumption based on simplicity of login/validation.

Answer (score 2):

If the site uses Web Forms and IIS has the standard set of default pages defined, then you can use file Default.aspx under the root directory of the web site to implement the login form.

Comment: @mason Still doesn't resolve anything, the link would still be www.mywebsite.com/default.aspx rather than just www.mywebsite.com

Comment: @mogorilla Not if `default.aspx` is configured as the default document.

Comment: @mason How would i configure the page to be a default document?

Comment: @mogorilla It depends on the server software.

Comment: https://www.bing.com/search?q=asp.Net%20How%20would%20i%20configure%20the%20page%20to%20be%20a%20default%20document%3F&qs=n&form=QBRE&pq=asp.net%20how%20would%20i%20configure%20the%20page%20to%20be%20a%20default%20document%3F

Comment: @mason it does not look like OP knows what framework they use - WebForms, ASP.Net MVC, something else... hopefully search link will give OP enough inf.

Comment: @mason So right now, locally using Visual Studio I cannot do that?

Comment: @mogorilla I said server software. Meaning the software that your hosting provider is using to provide the site. Or if you control the server, then likely Microsoft's IIS. You need to do a little research yourself. Figure out what framework you're using, figure out what web server software you're using. Then do a little research to figure out how to configure a default document in your specific software.

Comment: @mogorilla Keep it civilized. Alexei asked a perfectly valid question. You tagged this as ASP.NET, but there are multiple frameworks within ASP.NET and you need to know what you're using: Web Forms, MVC, Web Pages, Nancy etc.